# JavaScriptで変数の値が一致しなかった場合に処理を実行したい

Tags: javascript

パスワードのinputタグを二つ用意しました。一つ目のinputタグに入力された値と二つ目の確認用のinputタグの値をsubmitが押されたときに一致していなかった場合はアラートで「一致してない」と表示されるコードをかきたいのですが、教えていただきたいです。

---

**HTML**

```html
<tr>
  <th>パスワード</th>
  <td><input type="password" th:text="${loginPass1}"></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>パスワード確認</th>
  <td><input type="password" th:text="${loginPass2}"></td>
</tr>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var loginPass1= 'loginPass';
var loginPass2= 'loginPass';
// 
if (loginPass1 !== loginPass2) {
  alert('パスワードが一致していません');
}
```

Comment: JavaScriptの方で変数名に全角の数字が入っていますが、これは意図されたものでしょうか？

Comment: 質問に書かれたコードを実行した場合、結果はどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: node.jsタグがつけられていますがSpring Bootか何かでしょうか、なんにせよフロントJSで、タグに関係ない質問のように見えます

Comment: 申し訳ありません、半角が正しいです。

Comment: submitを押してもアラートはでなく、何も反応がないじょうたいです。

Comment: HTML側も全角数字になっているように見えます。

Comment: 何度もすいません。実行してみましたが、変化はありませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

たぶん、このようにすることができる。

```css
function passwordCheckFunction() {
  var loginPass1= document.getElementById("loginPass1").value;
  var loginPass2= document.getElementById("loginPass2").value;
  
  if(loginPass1 !== loginPass2){
    alert("パスワードが一致していません。")
  }
}
```

```html
 <tr>
  <th>パスワード</th>
  <td><input type="password" id = "loginPass1" th:text="${loginPass1}"></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>パスワード確認</th>
  <td><input type="password" id = "loginPass2" th:text="${loginPass2}"></td>
</tr>
<button type="button" class="passwordCheck" onclick="passwordCheckFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: 有難うございます。実行できました。

Comment: アラートなのですが、
ローカルホスト８０８０の内容
パスワードが一致していません

と出ます。ローカルホスト８０８０の内容が出ないようにユーザー向けに
作りたいのですが、どうしたらいいでしょうか？

Comment: すいません、いろいろしらべましたところ変更はできないみたいですね。ありがとうございました。m(__)m